# Sleuth not able to generate traces for JDBCTemplate access

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am exploring slueth for enabling tracing in our Apps. I get the API to API call logs in `zipkin` but I don't get any other `JDBC` calls logged. I have added below to my `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  sleuth:
    jdbc:
      # enable logging for datasource-proxy
      datasource-proxy:
        query:
          enable-logging: true
```

I have also added below to my `pom.xml`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ttddyy</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>${datasource-proxy.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Did I miss something to enable the Zipkin traces for JDBC templates?

Comment: Here you have an example of a working Sleuth & Data case - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples/tree/main/data can you please see what is different between your code and the sample?

Comment: This doesn't work on `jdbcTemplate`, it does work on the project with JPA and all.

Comment: Can you create a sample that replicates this issue and push it to github? Then file an issue in Spring Cloud Sleuth?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I would appreciate if you could take a look at my answer and root cause analysis bellow, as it seems there might be a spring auto configuration bug.

Comment: Can you file this as an issue together with a sample that replicates this? I'll try to look into that and fix the bug

Comment: thanks for helping: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31670

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I was able to solve the issue by using below

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.gavlyukovskiy</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-proxy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Instead of adding sleuth. I will work on a minimal example soon to see why Sleuth was not working

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: This is a spring-sleuth bug that will be fixed in the coming spring-cloud release: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2185

It seems I am having the same issue. Looks like when `TraceDataSourceDecoratorBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization()` is called

```
Map<String, DataSourceDecorator> decorators = this.applicationContext
        .getBeansOfType(DataSourceDecorator.class).entrySet().stream()
 .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE))
```

always return an empty map of `decorators`, when called on my `HikariDataSource`.

Also, in my case this was because the `HikariDataSource` was created before the `p6SpyDataSourceDecorator` was created. This had as a result the `decorators` to be empty and as a consequence the `HikariDataSource` not to be instrumented.

It seems Spring auto configuration as a bug. My work around is the following and now I have proper instrumentation:

```
@Primary
@Bean
@DependsOn("p6SpyDataSourceDecorator")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = createDataSource(properties, HikariDataSource.class);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(properties.getName())) {
        dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

The downside is that I had to allow circular dependencies.

Using:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```